# Set Color in DataBase when specific button clicked

Tags: javascript, java, html, sql

I have two buttons: one on click set color to red and other set color to green.
I want to store that value in database which button is clicked.
After that I want to get this color from database and want to set in background tag using get property in `<td bgcolor='' align="center" >` tag. 
How can I do it easily?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         </br>
        <h3> Please select your location </h3>
            <table border="1" width="50%" height="500" align="center"  >
            <tbody>
                <tr>           
                    <td bgcolor='' align="center" >
                        <jsp:useBean id="bean" scope="session" class="org.functions" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Park Here" color='<jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="color" value="red" />' name="en" onclick="this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='red'" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" color='<jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="color" value="green" />' name="en" onclick="this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='green'" />

                    </td>
<tr>
                    <form action="hello.jsp">
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Ok" style="width:100px"  />
                    </td>
                    </form>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>                     
    </body>
</html>

<%-- 
    Document   : hello
    Created on : Jun 19, 2016, 5:49:58 PM
    Author     : 
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">This is hello.jsp </h1>
        <jsp:useBean id="mybean" scope="session" class="org.Second" />

        <jsp:setProperty name="mybean" property="name" />
        <jsp:setProperty name="mybean" property="mail" />
        <jsp:useBean id="bean" scope="session" class="org.functions" />

        <%
                   // Second scnd = new Second();
                       int a= mybean.storevalue(); 
                       int b= bean.storeColor();                               
                 %>
                  <jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="color"  />
                  <jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="id"  />
        <table border="1" align="center">
            <thead>  
            <tr>
                <td>From Values</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <form action="ExampleDate.jsp" method="get">

            Start Date 
            <input type="date" name="date" id="d"  >

            Start Date 
            <input type="time" name="time"  >       
             <br></br>
        <input type="submit" value="hmmm" name="vxc" />
        </form>      
    </body>           
</html>

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class functions {
    private String color;
    private String id;

    /**
     * @return the color
     */

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    /**
     * @param color the color to set
     */
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int storeColor() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample;create=true; user=app; password=app";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO COLORTABLE(en, id) VALUES(?, ?)");
        ps.setString(1, color);
        ps.setString(2, id);
        int a = ps.executeUpdate();
        if(a==1){
            return a;
        }else{
            return a;
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: trigger a java method call on click of the button, since jsp bean will have the value , you can use that bean property to send the value to DAO

Comment: I am beginner, I thought to use some specific function but I didn't know how can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all things done with slightly changed logic but now I want when "Park Here" clicked it outer area should be red and when "Cancel" clicked it should be green but it shows inner color red and green. Is there any method which change background color to red and green.
code is here

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
       <td bgcolor="green" align="center" ><select name="place1"  >
       <option onclick="this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='red' "> Park Here</option>
       <option onclick="this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='green' "> Cancel </option>
       </select></td>

  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Here is output but I want outer color should be red or green like what this tag  done. 
IS there any method? Please tell me
[I want outer color should be red on click not inner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnndw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that in front end

On the backend you can only store values for the color

Comment: Can you please explain it? how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is with jQuery. You can use the addClass() routine for this. In case you want to restore the intial value of the previous button you can also implement the feature. For example:

```
//Restore all values
$("input").removeClass();
$("input").addClass("default");

//Set class that has the highlight color
$("#button2").addClass("highlight");
```

With this HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="button1"/>
<input type="button" id="button2"/>
```

And this CSS:

```
.default { background-color: blue;}
.highlight { background-color: yellow;}
```

Add onClick to the element to call the right functions.